# Could this cause an engine to jump time? (Asking from point of view of great igorance)

Tags: engine, car, timing-belt

2014 Ford Fiesta, with some option that involved the word "turbo", no photos.

I hit a bird, and almost immediately, my engine stopped running, and the car would no longer start. Mechanic says my engine jumped time. How possible is it that the timing jump happened due to something like a stray feather getting into the wrong place in the engine?

The engine was to be fair, already pretty fragile for various reasons. It's not surprising that it failed. But I'm wondering if it is possible the bird collision was the most immediate cause of the failure.

Comment: What is the make of your car? Could you post photos?

Comment: 2014 Ford Fiesta, it has the "turbo" option, sorry no photos as I am not with the car.

Comment: It does not seem likely that a bird strike would cause an engine to jump timing, but I suppose it is possible especially if your timing belt is very worn. Cars commonly jump timing at startup, bad/harsh shifts, sudden changes of engine speed/load. A Fiesta's timing belt should be changed at 150,000 miles, was it over this?

Comment: It wasn't over 150,000, it hadn't even reached 100,000 yet. But a few months ago it overheated and blew the main gasket. A cheap repair ("repair") was done by a friend of a friend but we knew the car was very possibly not going to last. I don't know if that would have an effect on the quality of the timing belt or the parts it directly connects to, so I'm basically wondering how plausible it is that the bird collision was a "straw that broke the camel's back" or just a coincidence. The failure happened like five seconds after the collision, is what makes me wonder.

Comment: I find it unlikely that a bird strike (it wasn't an ostrich by any chance?) could cause an engine loose timing.